# Importing a variable in Python?

Tags: python, import, sympy

I'm using sympy to write superscript using the `pretty_print` command. This needs to be imported along with some variables(algebra(x,y,etc.)) in order for the pretty_print command to work. If you dont import the variables(algebra) from sympy.abc, you will need to put the letters in quote marks `''` in which the pretty_print command won't work.

So for example if I print `x²` on the screen, i need to import `x` so it can be used in the program. Like this:

```
import sympy  
from sympy import pretty_text as exp   
from sympy.abc import x

equation= x**2

exp(equation)
```

This will print x² on the screen. The problem is if i assign a value to x, then it will no longer be equal to itself. If i print x directly after import from sympy.abc, it does this-

(pretending this is IDLE) >

```
>>> import sympy  
>>> from sympy import pretty_text as exp   
>>> from sympy.abc import x

>>> x
x
```

however if a make x 1

```
>>> import sympy  
>>> from sympy import pretty_text as exp   
>>> from sympy.abc import x

>>> x
x 
>>> x = 1
>>>x
1
```

Then i need to square `x` again,

```
>>> import sympy  
>>> from sympy import pretty_text as exp   
>>> from sympy.abc import x

>>> x
x 
>>> x = 1
>>>x
1 
>>> equation = x**2
>>> exp(equation)
1
```

It will just square 1. Even if it try to make `x = 'x'` again it is not the same since it will have the `''` around it. I can only fix this by importing it again. However, in my program i could end up needing to import any letter again so I would need to import a variable. I tried

```
from sympy.abc import x[0]
```

But that's invalid. So, is there any way i could import a varying letter?

Comment: Putting x in quotes creates a string, which is a completely separate object from a Symbol.

Comment: There are many misconceptions present in your question. Take a read of http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/gotchas.html and see if that clears some things up (particularly the variables section).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve symbols, do not assign any values to them - keep using symbols until you really need a solution.

For example:

```
In [15]: equation=sympy.sin(x**2)

In [16]: exp(equation)
   ⎛ 2⎞
sin⎝x ⎠

In [17]: result = equation.subs({'x': 2})

In [18]: result
Out[18]: sin(4)

In [19]: result.evalf()
Out[19]: -0.756802495307928
```

This does not change the `x` itself - later on:

```
In [23]: exp(sympy.log(x**.5))
   ⎛ 0.5⎞
log⎝x   ⎠
```

Keep your equations in the symbolic form for as long as needed and don't worry about the values themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import symbol names in SymPy. The abc module is just there for convenience for one-letter symbol names.

Just create the Symbol object with whatever name you want (this can be any string, including one created dynamically).

```
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> x
x
```

Also note that the name you give the symbol and the name of the Python variable holding that symbol need not be related. Indeed a Symbol has no idea what Python variable names it is bound to (this is how everything works in Python, not just SymPy)

```
>>> x = Symbol('y')
>>> x
y
```

You can also use `symbols` to create multiple symbols at once

```
>>> x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
```

Comment: Is this command imported from sympy? When i imported it from sympy and tried this i got and error saying object is not callable.

Comment: Yes, `Symbol` and `symbols` are both imported from SymPy.

Answer (score 0):

If you instead do:

```
import sympy.abc
x = sympy.abc.x
```

Then whenever you need your original value, just use `sympy.abc.x`. If you need to dynamically get a name:

```
getattr(sympy.abc, "x")
```

Where the literal could be replaced with any variable.

Comment: I understand your first part with using the x = sympy.abc.x , but could you explain the getattr(sympy.abc, "x") how do i use that with a variable?

Comment: @Nick `getattr()` is a built in that gets an attribute from an object, so if you have an instance of a class with a `name` attribute, `inst.name` is exactly equivalent to `getattr(inst, "name")` - modules work in the same way. `getattr(sympy.abc, "x")` is another way to write `sympy.abc.x`, except `"x"` could be any variable, allowing you to get different attributes dynamically.

Comment: i tried testing that and when i tried making "x" a variable it said the attribute must be a string. So how can i change the letter i want to import dynamically using this?

Comment: @Nick The variable needs to contain the name of the variable you wish to import, so if you wish to import a variable `sympy.abc.z`, the variable you pass to `getattr()` needs to contain the value `'z'`.

Comment: Why have I received a -1 for this?

Comment: I didn't mark you down 1. What i'm trying to say is this, the user of the program will input an equation and it will be read by my program. Since i dont know the exact letters the equation will have, I will use the variable a to represent the letter then import the letter that a represents. I'm not talking about algebra variable letters i need to input a letter that is unknown in the form of a python variable.

Comment: Yes, which is what `getattr()` will do for you. If `a` is a variable that represents the letter to import, then `getattr(module, a)` will give you the value of whatever `module.whatever_is_in_a` is.

Comment: >>> import sympy
>>> import sympy.abc
>>> from sympy.abc import r
>>> a= r

>>> getattr (sympy.abc, a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    getattr (sympy.abc, a)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
>>>

Comment: You are assigning `a` the value of `r`. If you want to get `r` to it's initial value, you can just to `r = a` later (so long as you don't change `a`. If you want to import it again as you suggested in your examples with my method, you need to use `'r'` as the value.

Comment: That would work if I were reassigning the value, but the question now is how do i know what letter i need to import if the user could have entered any letter at all? Say the letter in the qeuation is at input[3], i would set input[3] to variable, var= input[3] then i need to input that letter, how do I do it?

Comment: @Nick You are not being clear about what you mean to do, can you give some examples in the form of input/output of what you need to happen.

Comment: Well my program will allow a user to enter a quadratic equation that needs to be factored and then the program will output the solutions to the equation. Since quadratic equations always have a variable squared in them, i will need to be able to print that variable squared formally.

Comment: I voted down for a few reasons: 1. Your suggestion will only work for one letter variable names (and Greek letters), as that is all that is in `abc`. 2. Even for those, it is way convoluted. Just instantiate the Symbol. See my answer. 3. You suggest that `import sympy.abc; x = sympy.abc.x` and `from sympy.abc import x` are somehow different. They are exactly the same. 4. This doesn't address any of the confusion or poor code design present in the question (but rather suggests things that are wrong and gives more unpythonic code).

Comment: @asmeurer I was giving a solution without any knowledge of the library at hand. While my answer may not be the best solution given that knowledge, it's a valid answer to what the OP appeared to ask. In response to 3, they are different. One assigns a module to `sympy.abc`, allowing easy access to the module in future, one does not.